# Every sequential space is compactly generated, and both categories of spaces are cartesian closed. Do the products coincide for sequential spaces?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, compactness, product-space, cartesian-closed-categories

The categories of sequential spaces and compactly generated spaces both use a finer product than the one from $\textbf{Top}$ in order to be cartesian closed, and in both cases the product is arguably more natural as well, especially in the sequential case.

Every sequential space is (Hausdorff-) compactly generated. This can be seen either indirectly from it being a quotient of a metric space, or more explicitly by viewing sequential spaces as generated by maps from the compact (Hausdorff) space $\mathbb{N}\cup{\{\infty\}}$ that characterize convergent sequences.

Does the product of sequential spaces coincide with the one from compactly generated spaces? I'm interested both in the case of finite products and infinite products / exponentials.

Since every sequential space is compactly generated, abstract nonsense quickly shows that the sequential product topology is finer than or equal to the compactly generated product topology, but the other direction is harder. So it can be reduced to whether the (compact closed) product of sequential spaces is sequential.

Comment: For finite products, I think you can use that products of metric spaces are metric spaces and that sequential spaces are quotients of metric spaces, along with the fact that the product in a cartesian closed category has a right adjoint. So a product with a quotient in either of the factors maps to a quotient of the product.